# Snap, IO and acid-state

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework, acid-state

Trying to use acid-state in Snap, and I hit a roadblock.

Here is what I got so far.

First my acid-state related objects (it's a dummy book with a isbn number):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}

module Models where

import Prelude hiding ((.), id)
import Control.Category ((.))
import Control.Monad.Reader (asks)
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Data.SafeCopy (base, deriveSafeCopy)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Typeable (Typeable)
import Data.Acid (Update, Query, makeAcidic)
import Control.Monad.Reader (ask)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.Data (Data)

data Book = Book { isbn :: String }
     deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Data, Show, Typeable)

$(deriveSafeCopy 0 'base ''Book)

-- Retrieve the book's isbn
queryIsbn :: Query Book String
queryIsbn = isbn <$> ask

$(makeAcidic ''Book ['queryIsbn])
```

And then my actual attempt at integrating it with Snap. As you can see, I am having trouble defining __ doQuery__ function, that should return a string isbn:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Application where

import           Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import           Data.Text.Encoding (decodeUtf8)
import           Text.XmlHtml (Node(TextNode),Node (Element), 
                 getAttribute, setAttribute, nodeText)
import           Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import           Data.Maybe
import           Snap.Core
import           Snap.Snaplet
import           Snap.Snaplet.Heist (Heist, HasHeist(heistLens), heistInit,
                        addSplices, liftHeist, render)
import           Snap.Util.FileServe
import           Text.Templating.Heist (HeistT, Template, getParamNode)
import           Data.Lens.Template

import Models
import Data.Acid.Advanced (query')
import Data.Acid (AcidState, openLocalState, closeAcidState, IsAcidic, query)
import Data.Text (pack)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO, MonadIO)
import Snap (snapletValue)
import Data.Lens.Common (getL, (^$), (^.), Lens) 
import Control.Monad.Reader (ask, asks)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.Typeable (typeOf)


import Prelude hiding ((.), id)
import Control.Category ((.), id)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
type AppHandler = Handler App App

--------------
-- Acid
---------------
-- Used for holding data for the snapplet
data Acid st = Acid { _state ::  AcidState st }

-- Initializer function for the snapplet
seedBook =  Book "9213-23123-2311"

acidInit ::  SnapletInit b (Acid Book)
acidInit = makeSnaplet "storage" "Snaplet providing storage functionality" Nothing initializer

--The 'm' is the type variable of the MonadSnaplet type class. 'b' is the base state, and 'v' is the state of the current "view" snaplet (or simply, current state).
initializer :: Initializer b v (Acid Book)
initializer = do
      st <- liftIO (openLocalState seedBook)

      --onUnload (closeAcidState st)
      return $ Acid st

-----------------------
-- Snap Global State
--------------------

data App = App
    { _heist :: Snaplet (Heist App),
      _acid  :: Snaplet (Acid Book)
    }

makeLens ''App
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

instance HasHeist App where
    heistLens = subSnaplet heist

-----------------------------------------------
-- | Initialize app
-----------------------------------------------
appInit :: SnapletInit App App
appInit = makeSnaplet "app" "Website" Nothing $ do
    h <- nestSnaplet "" heist $ heistInit "templates"
    a <- nestSnaplet "isbn"  acid (acidInit)
    addRoutes routes --see below
    addSplices [ ("menuEntry", liftHeist menuEntrySplice) ]
    return $ App h a


------------------------------------------------
-- | The application's routes.
------------------------------------------------
routes :: [(ByteString, Handler App App ())]
routes = [ ("/books",    handleBooks)
         , ("/contact",  render "contact")
         , ("/isbn",     liftIO doQuery >>= writeBS )
         , ("",          serveDirectory "static")
         ]

-- Is this Function signature possible? Or must it run inside Snap or other monad?
doQuery :: IO ByteString
doQuery = do    -- ???????????
        --somehow retrieve acid store from snaplet
        --run queryIsbn on it
        --return isbn string
        return "BLAH"


handleBooks :: Handler App App ()
handleBooks = render "books"
```

Any help on what I am missing would be greatly appreciated. If something is not clear, please let me know and I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

MathematicalOrchid is correct, the simplest answer to your problem is to use liftIO on the openLocalState call.

But from a broader view, what you're doing here has already been done for you by the [snaplet-acid-state](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snaplet-acid-state) package, so I would recommend that you just use that.  The repository also includes an [example application](https://github.com/mightybyte/snaplet-acid-state/blob/master/examples/Site.hs) demonstrating how to use it.

Comment: Hi mightybyte, thanks for the recommendation. I am actually following the snaplet-acid-state snaplet - I just want to write it without it (using only acid-state) to understand what is going on under the covers. Also, it uses an older acid-state package :-(

Comment: snaplet-acid-state [uses liftIO](https://github.com/mightybyte/snaplet-acid-state/blob/master/src/Snap/Snaplet/AcidState.hs#L79).  I also just uploaded a new version to hackage that allows the most recent version of acid-state.

Comment: Thanks, i figured out the initialize function! Could you take a look at my revised code? In particular, I am not sure how your code works for getting the acid-state object from the snaplet (`doQuery` function). You do it with classes, but I want to try to understand it without classes.

Comment: I know your busy, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the [query](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snaplet-acid-state/0.2.2/doc/html/Snap-Snaplet-AcidState.html#v:query) function from Snap.Snaplet.AcidState just like in [the example](https://github.com/mightybyte/snaplet-acid-state/blob/master/examples/Site.hs#L76).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the packages you're using, but it *looks like* the problem is simply that `openLocalState` is an `IO` action, but your type signature requires it to be an `Initializer` action.

Fixing it might be as simple as stuffing a call to `liftIO` in there. I'm not really sure though... I don't know which module each of these types comes from.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I've added all the imports to the question, let me know if it helps. I'll try the `liftIO` in the meantime.